# Cumulative sum of each each variable of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, na, cumsum

In my code below, I want to first remove the `Variable` for which i do not have any value (Ie., **F** should be removed where all the values are 'NA'). then i am trying to find accumulated values of each `Variable`. I tried with the following code but i am not getting anything out of it.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(50)

DF <- data.frame(Days = 1:5, A = runif(5,0,3), S = runif(5,1,6),  F = matrix(NA, 5,1), C = runif(5,2,4))
DF_1 <- gather(DF, -Days, key = "Variable", value = "Value")
DF_2 <- DF_1 %>% 
  filter(Variable == "NA") %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_Sum = cumsum(Value))
```

**Output**

For `Variable A` I should get something like below- similar for others

```
> A <- cumsum(DF$A)
> A
[1] 2.126181 3.439161 4.039176 6.340374 7.879859
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'Variable',  `filter` out the  groups having all `NA` 'Value', then do the cumulative sum of 'Value' after replacing the NA with 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF_1 %>%           
   group_by(Variable) %>% 
   filter(!all(is.na(Value))) %>% 
   mutate(Value = cumsum(replace_na(Value, 0)))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   Variable [3]
#    Days Variable Value
#   <int> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1     1 A         2.13
# 2     2 A         3.44
# 3     3 A         4.04
# 4     4 A         6.34
# 5     5 A         7.88
# 6     1 S         1.22
# 7     2 S         5.72
# 8     3 S         9.95
# 9     4 S        11.2 
#10     5 S        12.7 
#11     1 C         2.78
#12     2 C         5.32
#13     3 C         8.60
#14     4 C        10.8 
#15     5 C        13.3
```

---

If we use the 'wide' format 'DF', then use `mutate_at`

```
DF %>%
   mutate_at(-1, cumsum)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I will be plotting all the `Variable` via `Faceting` so I need the stations to be removed completely instead making it zero.

Comment: @Hydro I added `filter` with `is.na`

Comment: This is close- I am wondering i would also lose rows where a `Variable` is missing only one record on a given day. For example, if `A` is missing record on `Day 3`, it will be wiped out. Is there a way to remove the `Variable` only when it has no value for all the `Days` considered?

Comment: @Hydro Updaed the post

Comment: @Hydro Do you want the cumsum to return NA where there are NA

Comment: Would i be better off if i use `mutate(Value = cumsum(Value, na.rm = T))`? not sure if this will work at all.

Comment: @Hydro `cumsum` doesn't  have `na.rm` argument